# apache 2.2: how can I set up a VirtualHost inside the RootDirectory?

Tags: apache-http-server

I want to set up a VirtualHost inside the RootDirectory. For example,

My project is in `C:/myproject`

and I want to access with `http://localhost/myproject`

**EDIT:**

I've made an alias inside the `httpd-vhosts.conf`, however I don't have permissions.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/apache-2.2/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    Alias /test "D:\arbol\documentos\test"  
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this code below the proper way to give permissions?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/apache-2.2/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    Alias /test "D:\arbol\documentos\test"  

      <Directory "D:\arbol\documentos\test">        
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
      </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What happens if you go to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <Directory "D:\arbol\documentos\test">        
         Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
         Require all granted
  </Directory>
```